# Errors while deploying Azure function in Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Hi I am trying to deploy few functions that I created in vs code to my azure function app. I am using python stack with linux.
At first, functions were deployed successfully and started running. But after doing some changes in *init*.py (The main code), I am getting error while deploying them to function app.

Sometimes I get `Error: (intermediate value).parsedBody.map is not a function` error and sometime `Deployment not found` error.

Not sure the reason behind these errors.

I tried stopping the function app in portal before deploying, verified all json configuration files (host.json, function.json).  I tried deleting existing functions after disabling them but then I got this error `Failed to delete PortfolioNOIQuater. Error: [object Object]`.

Comment: Could you share the python code?

Comment: Did you try creating new function app and deploy your functions?

Comment: @Will thanks for giving your time however I can't share the code here. I am sorry. I tried deleting it and creating new function app like Pravallika suggested. It's working now. Still I would like to know the reason behind this error. The new function app is just like the old one and it's working fine.

Comment: @PravallikaKV I did what you suggested and it worked. New function app is just like the old one and it's working fine. Still I would like to know the reason behind this error.

Comment: @naam_nrj, Can you try to deploy your function to the old function app now and check if you get the same error?

Comment: @PravallikaKV um.... I deleted the old one.

Comment: This error usually occurs due to the function code (ex: if the request body is not being parsed correctly) or if there is any misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: (intermediate value).parsedBody.map is not a function

- Generally, this error occurs if there is anything wrong with the code or if the functionapp is not getting expected input.
- In your case, I suspect there must be issue with the existing functions or your function app.
- To avoid these errors:

1. *Debug the code and check if there is anything missing*.
2. *As I mentioned in the comments, create a new function app and deploy your function.*

> I tried deleting existing functions after disabling them but then I got this error `Failed to delete PortfolioNOIQuater. Error: [object Object]`.

I came across few cases with the similar error while deleting the function in Azure function app.

- One workaround is to stop the function app and try to disable/delete the function.
- If your function is not running on consumption plan,you can delete the unnecessary function files from KUDU site.